# Android - LayoutInflater - Cant make textview stay below another textview

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater

I am using a LayoutInflater to fill out a grid view using a GridAdapter, but when i try to place a textView below another textView within the layout i am inflating, it ends up being above my textView instead of below. When i change it to layout_above instead, it doesnt even appear on the screen.
Layout that i inflate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/menuBookModel">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bookImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bookName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test Text"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/personalTag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bookName"
    android:text="(Personal)"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="15sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

My java code where i am inflating:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(view == null){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_book_model, null);
    }

    TextView bookName = view.findViewById(R.id.bookName);
    TextView personalTag = view.findViewById(R.id.personalTag);
    ImageView bookImage = view.findViewById(R.id.bookImage);

    bookImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String s = String.valueOf(view.getTag());
            aListener.chooseBook(s);
        }
    });


    int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(books[i], "string", context.getPackageName());
    //if id == 0 the book is custom, and therefore it has the custom name
    if(id == 0){
        bookName.setText(books[i]);
    } else {
        bookName.setText(context.getString(id));
        personalTag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    bookImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(random.nextInt(255),random.nextInt(255),random.nextInt(255)));

    bookImage.setTag(books[i]);
    return view;
}
```

How it looks in the preview:
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsRXV.png)

But this is how it look in practice:
[In practice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxfZj.png)

Comment: Looks like you are setting bookName value for personalTag and viceversa. Can you check your java code for the values that you are setting in the text views? To be sure, you can comment all the setText in your java code and re build the app, then it should come as expected.

Comment: Not sure this will help but maybe try changing your inflate method:

`view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_book_model, parent, false);` - this will just ensure your layout parameters are created correctly for the viewgroup the inflater will attach the view to.

Comment: I am not exactly sure about what you mean. @Shivam Pokhriyal

Comment: @quaternion What should the parent variable refer to? Should it be to the variable viewGroup?

Comment: @Emil Yeah sorry dude, can't edit anymore. Try: ```view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_book_model, viewGroup, false);```

Comment: I tried but still the same outcome as before :/

Comment: @Emil Just check one thing, comment all the lines where you are setting text in the 2 textviews. Check if the position is correct? It appears to me as if you are setting different values in textviews.

Comment: One other quick thing to try is when you set `android:layout_below="@+id/bookName"` it might be good to omit the '+', as it may be assigning an ID instead of waiting for layout to complete. So replace with `android:layout_below="@id/bookName"` - Just taking stabs in the dark here

Comment: I seem to have identified the problem, it seems like the textView personalTag doesnt recognize that the textView bookName is being moved when it being centered, and therefore personalTag doest adapt and therefore not placed below bookName. So it works when i hardcode the location values, but not when i try to make it dynamic with centering it

Comment: @Emil yeah that's the issue, did you find a fix though? and which android version are you running it on?

Comment: Yes i figured it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to handle `personalTag` visibility when the `id` is 0, because it may not be visible when the view is being recycled:

```
if(id == 0){
    bookName.setText(books[i]);
    personalTag.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    bookName.setText(context.getString(id));
    personalTag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Also avoid setting your root `RelativeLayout` with `match_parent` as height, they usually *break* in `AdapterViews`, try `wrap_content` or any hard values, or adjust your layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/menuBookModel">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bookImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test Text"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/personalTag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bookName"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="(Personal)"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How is visibility related to order of text views?

Comment: I tried to change it. But now it is also shown wrongly in the preview

Comment: @Emil Maybe something to do with your root layout, could you try the xml in the answer again?

Comment: @Aaron The XML in the awnser wroks well, and i tried that myself, but i am very picky with the posistion, and i would love to have my bookName exactly centered in the middle of its parent, with the personalTag below, instead of the LinearLayot centered. I might just have to live with it, i am not sure.

Comment: @Emil Oh I'm sure you can do exactly what you want, and I'm now sure that it's the height, you just can't use match_parent for the root RelativeLayout, try a hard value or wrap_content.

Comment: @Emil Seems like it was setting the `android:layout_height="100dp"` in the RelativeLayout that made this work.

Comment: I figured it out, i took the personalTag out of the linearLayout, and placed it below the linearLayout, so it now works perfectly :) It also had to do with the layout_height yes :)

Comment: Awesome! Don't forget the change the visibility state as well `personalTag.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`, or you will run into another issue :)

Comment: Haha yhe, you just saved me from another minor bug :)